# Знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы

Tags: php, mysql

Вместо кириллицы отображаются вопросительные знаки (не символы)

- Кодировка файла UTF-8 без BOM
- В .htaccess указан utf-8
- MySQL полностью переведена в utf8mb4_general_ci (в самой БД киррилица
  отображается адекватно)
- Кодировка в < head > указана верно

Сам php:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
  SELECT * FROM post 
  WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'

 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY test
 ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Customer Name</th>
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>Postal Code</th>
     <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["title"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["test"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
  }

?>
```

Быть может кто сталкивался с подобным? Целый день мучаюсь.

Comment: Проверьте видит ли браузер верное указание на кодировку =) попробуйте в ручную указать браузеру кодировку.
Если файл действительно в верной кодировке, выведите тестовое сообщение с кирилице (echo 'Проверка!';)

Answer (score -1):

Помимо первой строчки можно попробовать добавить ещё две (так чтобы на 100% быть уверенным):

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

И ещё.. текстовые поля таблиц в БД должны быть в кодировке utf8_general_ci, скорее всего в этом проблема (после смены кодировки таблиц, их скорее всего придется перезаполнять, так как там будут битые данные)

Comment: Это ни к чему не привело

Comment: @noobsaibot хм, можно узнать что конкретно указанно в head, в htaccess? И ещё проверьте точно ли у всех таблиц базы данных и у всех текстовых полей указана кодировка utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: @noobsaibot в общем мне кажется главная проблема в не правильной кодировке в базе данных, написал в ответе подробнее

Comment: < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" > и  AddDefaultCharset utf-8 в .htaccess под Apache. У всех текстовых полей указана кодировка utf8mb4_general_ci (уже даже создал отдельную таблицу в этой БД)

Comment: @noobsaibot должна быть кодировка utf8_general_ci (не mb4)

Comment: У меня уже была такя мысль, только что еще раз изменил на utf8_general_ci и обратно - безрезультатно

Comment: @noobsaibot нужно изменить кодировку и полностью перезаполнить все данные

Comment: и все же дело не в этом...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through
Решением стало mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8'); 
Благодарю Вас за уделенное время.